How to add health probe to a classic load balancer deployed as part of Azure cloud services extended support application
Microsoft document says we can do it through the service def file. Is there any way we can do it via ARM template?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/schema-csdef-loadbalancerprobe
I tried adding probe property in json but I see the error - Invalid request format. Unable to parse request. Do we have any quick start template to help?

PLease share the code you tried @vidya


Adding health probe to a classic load balancer deployed as part of Azure cloud services extended support application.

As per the MSdoc when we are working around the Cloud Services (extended support) and creating load balancer probes we need to achieve this using .csdef files not with ARM templets.
If you still want to use ARM templets and define this in .csdef files.
deploy.json:
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "myPublicIP",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "publicIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers",
      "apiVersion": "2021-02-01",
      "name": "vkLoadBalancer",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'myPublicIP')]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "frontendIPConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "myFrontEndConfig",
            "properties": {
              "publicIPAddress": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses', 'myPublicIP')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        "backendAddressPools": [
          {
            "name": "myBackEndPool"
          }
        ],
        "probes": [
          {
            "name": "myProbe",
            "properties": {
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "port": 80,
              "intervalInSeconds": 5,
              "numberOfProbes": 2
            }
          }
        ],
        "loadBalancingRules": [
          {
            "name": "myLoadBalancingRule",
            "properties": {
              "frontendIPConfiguration": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', 'vkLoadBalancer'), '/frontendIPConfigurations/myFrontEndConfig')]"
              },
              "backendAddressPool": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', 'vkLoadBalancer'), '/backendAddressPools/myBackEndPool')]"
              },
              "probe": {
                "id": "[concat(resourceId('Microsoft.Network/loadBalancers', 'vkLoadBalancer'), '/probes/myProbe')]"
              },
              "protocol": "Tcp",
              "frontendPort": 80,
              "backendPort": 80,
              "idleTimeoutInMinutes": 4,
              "enableFloatingIP": false,
              "loadDistribution": "Default"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

deployment succeeded:


Refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services-extended-support/deploy-template

@Vidya Please check if the solution above helped you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.
